# RMQ using two fenwick trees (binary indexed tree)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, fenwick-tree, rmq, binary-indexed-tree

Based on this [paper](http://www.ioinformatics.org/oi/pdf/v9_2015_39_44.pdf), I found that it is quite brilliant to use two BITs to do RMQ in `O(lg N)`, as it is easier to code than segment tree, and the paper claims it performs better than other data structures as well.

I understand how to build the tree and how to do query operation, yet I am confused about the update operation. Here's the quotes:

> We make the following observation: when we generate the associated intervals of
>   the nodes we pass by, we can cover the whole interval **[ p + 1, y ]** by starting from node
>   p + 1 and **climbing the first tree (Fig. 2.1)**. So instead of doing a query for every node we
>   update, we compute the results of the queries on the fly by climbing the tree once.
>
> Analogously, we can update all the intervals of the form **[ x, p – 1]** by starting from
>   node p – 1 and **climbing the second tree (Fig. 2.2)**. The same algorithm is applied for
>   updating both trees.

I suspect it should be the other way round: for finding minimum of interval **[p+1, y]**, we should use the **second tree** instead of the first one; for finding minimum of interval **[x, p-1]**, we should use the **first tree** instead.

My question is: Am I correct? If no, can someone give a simple example to demonstrate how the update operation works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is a bit ambiguous. I guess they've meant that for `[p+1,y]` you climb the first three starting from `p+1`, but use the second tree to query.

Let's imagine that you update value at 10-th index (from the paper). You will have to answer queries for `[x, 10 - 1]` & `[10 + 1, y]` while updating the trees. In order to do this efficiently you build two "climbing" lists:

`CLB1` by climbing the first tree from `p+1`: `{11, 12}`, which correspond to the next intervals: `[11..11]`, `[12..15]` of the second tree

`CLB2` by climbing the second tree from `p-1`: `{9, 8}`, which correspond to the next intervals: `[9..9]`, `[1..8]` of the first tree

Now you start the update of the first tree by climbing up the first tree starting with 10.

10 - trivial update

12 - you need to query `[9..9]`, `{10}`, `[11..11]`, `{12}`. You have an answer for `[9..9]` from the `BIT1` by taking the first member of `CLB2`. And you have an answer for `[11..11]` from the `BIT2`, by taking the first member of `CLB1`. `{10}` and `{12}` are trivial.

16 - you need to query `[1..9]`. `{10}`, `[11..15]` (no `{16}` as it is fictive). You are taking `[1..9]` from `BIT1` by taking first two items of `CLB2`. You are taking `[11..15]` from `BIT2` by taking first two items of `CLB1`. `{10}` is trivial.

As you can see for the left queries you take answers from the first tree using the climbing history from the `p-1` of the second tree. For the right queries you take answers from the second tree using the climbing history of `p+1` of the first tree.

Similar process is used for updating the right tree.

**Update: process for 9th node**

In case of updating 9-th index we have next `CLB`s:

`CLB1`: `{10, 12}`, intervals: `[10..11]`, `[12..15]` of `BIT2`.

`CLB2`: `{8}`, intervals: `[1..8]` of `BIT1`

Updating `BIT1`:

9 - trivial

10 - trivial (we need only `{9}` and `{10}`)

12 - we need first entry from `CLB1` - `[10..11]`, and `{12}` with `{9}`

16 - we need two first entries from `CLB1` - `[10..11] U [12..15]`, first entry from `CLB2` - `[1..8]` and `{9}`

Updating `BIT2`:

9 - trivial

8 - we need first two entries from `CLB1` - `[10..11] U [12..15]` and `{9}` with `{8}`

0 - we need first two entries from `CLB1` - `[10..11] U [12..15]` and first entry from `CLB2` - `[1..8]` and `{9}`

Comment: Got it, such a great relief now. I still do not get the intuitive that why this query / update algorithm works though, the paper only taught us the way, but does not explain why... Thanks anyway at least I can apply this on some problems now

Comment: Hmmm but I can't use the same algorithm on updating 9th-index (in the paper)...can you do one more example on it please...

Comment: @shole, you're right, I guess I missed something (worked with this structure 4 years ago), I'll dig deeper whenever I have some spare time, and will share the info.

Comment: @shole, my first impression was incorrect - the method works, and I didn't change anything in the logic. The idea is that while climbing `p+1` and `p-1` in corresponding `BIT`s you receive enough info to update both trees from `p`. I suggest you to think in terms of intervals rather than in terms of trees while performing an update (forget about the structure you have and just look at the answers that you can get).

Comment: I agree each [x, y] can be covered by climb list1 and 2, but what is the general algorithm? It is easy for us yo see which segments from BIT1 and BIT2 can cover [x, y] but what is the general rule behind...

Comment: @shole, While climbing you can easily determine which segments you need and whether they were already accumulated by the previous step. Consider that they only grow. So prepare them beforehand and use as required.

Comment: I think that is the correct direction to handle update operation...yet I think turns out the implementation is not really much easier than segment tree (though the performance is vastly improved, someone on Codeforces did a benchmark for me)